# Firebase firestore unable to read all data (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to read data from my firestore cloud database but I'm unable to!

Here is my database:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = mFirestore.collection("Users");
collectionReference.whereEqualTo("Mobile", mobile.getText().toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        mobile.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(sign_up_page.this, "Mobile Number Already In Use!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: So what error are you seeing? Write a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're telling the `collectionReference` to find `.whereEqualTo` `Mobile` right after the `Users` in the document section.

Instead, you can try :

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document("XSPH..."); // fill with the whole item which starts by `XSPH`
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

          String mobileItem = documentSnapshot.get("Mobile"); // Declare it as string or integer or whatever you want in here

          Log.d("TAG", documentSnapshot.getString("Mobile")); // or try this
          // Print the mobileItem 

            ...
            ..
```

**Take a look:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: Those document names are unique ids, I want the code to traverse through all the documents and find the occurance of mobile number if any.

Comment: So, removing `document("XSPH...")` and doing the listener on the whole documents will help.